# How can I make a sliding layout to show options (from the upper corner)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How can I make a sliding layout to show options (from the upper corner)?
(Like the picture)
(Android Studio, Kotlin)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeuLq.png)

Answer (score 0):

A `NavigationDrawer`? [Here's how you do it](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) if you're using the `Navigation` library (no relation), or [here's a pretty detailed tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer)